# How to modify AWS Lambda Node.js code to filter logs from AWS Cloudwatch

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have logs from an EC2 instance being streamed to AWS cloudwatch, I am then trying to use AWS Lambda to filter these logs and pass them to an event bridge for further routing. I am currently using the following code (which I got from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample) to filter the logs

```
var zlib = require('zlib');
exports.handler = function(input, context) {
    var payload = Buffer.from(input.awslogs.data, 'base64');
    zlib.gunzip(payload, function(e, result) {
        if (e) { 
            context.fail(e);
        } else {
            result = JSON.parse(result.toString('ascii'));
            console.log("Event Data:", JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
            context.succeed();
        }
    });
};
```

Currently this code takes in filters from the aws-cli and applies them to the logs, I would like to add my filters programmatically by adding filters into the code with if statements, how do I alter my code to allow this? Alternatively would this be more easily accomplished in either Python or Java?